# How to get dispatch redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm learning redux and react. I am following some tutorials, in order to make a app.

I have this `action`:

```
export function getDueDates(){
  return {
    type: 'getDueDate',
    todo
  }
}
```

this is the store:

```
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import duedates from './reducers/duedates'

export default createStore(duedates)
```

This is the reducer:

import Immutable from 'immutable'

```
export default (state = Immutable.List(['Code More!']), action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'getDueDate':
      return state.unshift(action.todo)
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

and in the `entry point js` I have this:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import store from './app/store'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'

import App from './app/Components/AppComponent';


ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Now, (according to some examples), I should call `getDueDate` from the `dispatch` but I dont get how to get the `dispatch` on the component, to trigger the action

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `connect` from `react-redux` package. It has two functions as params, `mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps`, which you are interested in now. As per answer from Nick Ball, which is partially right, you will be exporting like this:

`export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App)`

and your `mapDispatchToProps` will look something like this:

```
function mapDispatchToProps (dispatch, ownProps) {
  return {
    getDueDate: dispatch(getDueDate(ownProps.id))
  }
}
```

as long as your component connected to the store has property id passed from above, you'll be able to call `this.props.getDueDate()` from inside of it.

EDIT: There is probably no need of using an `id` in this case, however my point was to point out that props go as second parameter :)

Comment: This seems to work!, is there a easy workarroud for making a async call to the server on the reducer? It seems to update the prop directly when calling the action, and when async call ends, it does not change the prop

Comment: Not the reducer, use `thunk-middleware` which allows you to dispatch functions. This function has two params, `dispatch` and `getState`. This allows you to do whatever and dispatch whatever you want in the function.

Comment: This is what I'm talking about: http://danmaz74.me/2015/08/19/from-flux-to-redux-async-actions-the-easy-way/

Comment: I will just add one more thing, reducers should ALWAYS BE PURE FUNCTIONS, ie. without side-effects. It should only receive state, action and return new state. Everything that doesn't fit in this description should probably be handled elsewhere (action most probably).

Comment: great! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

The missing piece here is the [`connect`](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options) function from `react-redux`. This function will "connect" your component to the store, giving it the `dispatch` method.  There are variations on how exactly to do this, so I suggest reading the documentation, but a simple way would be something like this:

```
// app/Components/AppComponent.js

import { connect } from 'react-redux';

export class App extends React.Component {

    /* ...you regular class stuff */

    render() {

        // todos are available as props here from the `mapStateToProps`
        const { todos, dispatch } = this.props;

        return <div> /* ... */ </div>;
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        todos: state.todos
    };
}

// The default export is now the "connected" component
// You'll be provided the dispatch method as a prop
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(App);
```

Comment: No, you shouldn't do it like this! You should use second parameter of connect, mapDispatchToProps, to create functions that are then passed as props.

Comment: I understand that there are different ways to inject the actions and I happen to agree with you, but the question was not about best practices for connecting a component it was about how to connect a component in the first place.  Not using the `mapDispatchToProps` method was simply a way of keeping the number of new concepts to a minimum.

Comment: Well he is actually asking for a way to get access to `dispatch` from inside of his component, the way I proposed is the right way to do so... The way you suggest inclines that he should now pass `dispatch` itself down to child components, which is essentially wrong.

Comment: I'll stop after this, but again, we're talking about best practices.  The way I listed isn't "wrong" because it will work.  It's literally from the documentation:  https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#inject-dispatch-and-todos.    There's a lot of new concepts to learn in React/Redux world so I thought it'd be better to start simpler and grow from there.

Comment: Well, the fact that it works doesn't make it right yet :) I get your point though, on the contrary, I believe that when you start learning things, you just might as well learn them the proper way...